# Is Nafil allowed after Faraz of Asr ?

Tags: salat, nafl

I performed *Nafil* prayer(namaz) after *Asr Faraz* namaz, one person came and said you should not perform any namaz (Salah) after Asr Faraz.

I would like to know is it allowed to offer *Nafil* namaz after Farz namaz of Asr?

There is a same doubt with offering *Nafil* namaz after Fajr. Would anyone clarify on this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This question was asked [here](http://www.exploring-islam.com/nawafil-after-asr.html) and has been answered in detail.

Comment: @dotNET, I've summarized an answer from the link that you have provided, Jazakaalah.

Answer (score 4):

A Hadith from Shahih-Al-Bhukhari states that

> "Aa’ishah (ra) said: Anytime God’s messenger (pbuh) came to my house
>   after the Asr he prayed two Rak’ah."  ([Bukhari, 593](http://authentichadithfoundation.org/sahih-bukhari-593/))

The scholars of Islam have tried to find a reconciliation between Hadiths like the above and the ones that narrate that the Prophet (pbuh) forbade reading prayers after the Asr, however there is no agreement on this. Some believe that the Prophet (pbuh) did not continue to read this prayer. Others believe that the Prophet (pbuh) read it for a specific reason (i.e. missing the after-the- Zuhr- non-obligatory prayers) but then continued reading it regularly because once he read it, as a prophet, he would make it upon himself to make it his habit and to read it every day. Others consider this prayer to be specific to the Prophet (pbuh). Then there are those who believe that the directives that forbid reading prayers after Asr have abrogated the allowance that can be derived from the above Hadith. However, others have said the opposite, i.e. it is the above allowance that have abrogated the forbidding directives.
- **Refer to Fat'h al-Bari, Sharh al-Bukhari by Ibn Rajab, 5:78-100**

The above is perhaps one of the reasons that the four famous schools of Fiqh have different views about reading Nafl after Asr.

- Hanafies and Habalies do not allow it.
- Malikies and Shafe'ies do allow it but consider it disliked (Makruh).
- View among the Shia scholars is that reading prayers after the Asr
  prayer is neither forbidden nor disliked.

There are another groups of Hadiths that narrate that the Prophet (pbuh) prohibited praying and burying the dead during sunrise and sunset and when the sun is in its meridian. It is likely that the Hadiths that forbid reading prayers after the Subh prayer and after the Asr prayer in fact refer to the times when it gets very close to sunset or sunrise.

[Source](http://www.exploring-islam.com/nawafil-after-asr.html).

Comment: the link to the hadith is broken. here is an alternative: http://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/69

Answer (score -2):

Please read Bukhari 563,564 & 565 this nafil salat name is mussabvatul asr maybe i hope so and one suggestion don't pray outside or public place .